# Using Xcode for multiple developer IDs

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am quite new all this iPhone stuff. I have no such clear IDea yet about provisioning profile etc.

I will be using my mac machine for two different developer IDs,one for my own and other for the startup where I am working in. Now,how can I use xCode to submit my apps in two different IDs?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly specify a signing identity (as long as they have different names) and a provisioning profile GUID.

**EDIT:** `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer: John Doe (ABCDEF)` and `PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*] = provisioning-profile-guid` in the config (or on the command line). Or in the project settings, search for "sign" and use the nice GUI menu.

Alternatively, use a different user account for your work builds.

**EDIT:** System Preferences → Accounts and add a new user. It also helps if you enable fast user-switching under "Login Options".

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain both parts?

Comment: Adding a new account is not working for me because when I Log into new account,no input device works other than Keyboard